# Escaping special characters like ) in regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary and string like :

```
d = {'ASAP':'as soon as possible', 'AFAIK': 'as far as I know'}
s = 'I will do this ASAP, AFAIK.  Regards, X'
```

I want to replace the values of dict with the keys of the dict in the string and return

```
I will do this <as soon as possible>, <as far as I know>.  Regards, X.
```

I use

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys())+r')\b')
result=pattern.sub(lambda x: '<'+d[x.group()]+'>',s)
print"result:%s" % result
```

I have a dictionary like:

```
{'will you wash some pants for me please :-)': 'text'}
```

The smiley is causing an error.  How do I change my regular expression to suit any characters like smileys?

Comment: have you tried using `re.escape` on the keys?

Comment: Really all you're asking is how to escape special characters in a regular expression....the dictionary has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape any regular expression metacharacters with [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, d)) + r')\b')
```